# Azure Data Factory- Complex Json Data Transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am looking to transform json blob data to relational format using ADF as follows :

```
"reseller": {
                "en-ca": [
                    {
                        "MarketPlaceResellerId": "1",
                        "ResellerPrice": "",
                        "ResellerFormattedPrice": "",
                        "InventoryStatus": 3
                    }
                ],
                "en-us": [
                    {
                        "MarketPlaceResellerId": "2",
                        "ResellerPrice": "",
                        "ResellerFormattedPrice": "",
                        "InventoryStatus": 4
                    }
                ],
                "fr-ca": [
                    {
                        "MarketPlaceResellerId": "1",
                        "ResellerPrice": "",
                        "ResellerFormattedPrice": "",
                        "InventoryStatus": 3
                    }

Output :
                      
Market      MarketPlaceResellerId   ResellerPrice   ResellerFormattedPrice  InventoryStatus 
En-ca                  1               3 
En-us                  2               4
```

what is the transformation ADF that can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ADF data flow transformation called "Flatten" for each of the arrays

Comment: Thanks for ur reply . after flattening arrays i will get 12 different rows . how do i get values "en-us" as row values and transform rows into 4 columns

Comment: If you want to turn column values into row values, use Unpivot